# What is the puripose of `additional receiver type` in Kotlin lambda declaration?

Tags: function, kotlin, lambda, kotlin-extension

I am a java developer but develop Kotlin for two weeks and during test implementation I've found interesting construction :

```
every {
    mockedObject.foo(arg)
} returns bar
```

I've checked `every` finction declaration:

```
/**
 * Starts a block of stubbing. Part of DSL.
 *
 * Used to define what behaviour is going to be mocked.
 *
 * @sample
 * interface Navigator {
 *   val currentLocation: String
 * }
 *
 * val navigator = mockk<Navigator>()
 * every { navigator.currentLocation } returns "Home"
 *
 * println(navigator.currentLocation) // prints "Home"
 * @see [coEvery] Coroutine version.
 */
fun <T> every(stubBlock: MockKMatcherScope.() -> T): MockKStubScope<T, T> = MockK.useImpl {
    MockKDsl.internalEvery(stubBlock)
}
```

I've got that it is a function which accepts a single argument named `stubBlock`

It is a lambda which accepts no arguments but returns `T`

But I don't understand meaning of `MockKMatcherScope` here

```
(stubBlock: MockKMatcherScope.() -> T)
```

Looks like it is [somehow related](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#function-types):

```
Function types can optionally have an additional receiver type, which is specified before the dot in the notation: the type A.(B) -> C represents functions that can be called on a receiver object A with a parameter B and return a value C. Function literals with receiver are often used along with these types.
```

But I stil don't understand how to use that additiona receiver type.

### UPDATE

My IDE helped me to convert it to:

```
    val every: MockKStubScope<String, String> = every(
        stubBlock = fun MockKMatcherScope.(): String{
            return mockedObject.foo(arg)
        },
    )
    every.returns(bar)
```

Looks like it is related to extension functionality in Kotlin

So looks like I pass instance of `MockKMatcherScope` enriched with 1 functions

Comment: You can treat the receiver (`MockKMatcherScope` here) as the `this` in the function body. The documentation [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver) can hopefully clarify it.

Comment: @mkobit
 I played with my idea and now I think that it is just an extension.

Is it correct ?

Comment: It is related to extensions, yes. The concept is the same - function receives an argument which is represented inside the function as `this`.